# resize the content property's image

Tags: css

I have an unordered list of links and each link has a unique id.
I'm using that id with the `:before` selector to place
the associated website's favicon before the link (using the content property).
One of these icons is twice the size of the others.
Is there any way to change the size of this icon using CSS?
If the answer is no, is there any way to do this other than editing the image?

Visual reference:

[image]

Here is what I tried (and it doesn't seem to work):

```
#geog:before
{
    content: url("icons/geogebra.ico") " ";
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the height of an image in CSS :before/:after pseudo-elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977957/can-i-change-the-height-of-an-image-in-css-before-after-pseudo-elements)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I've run into the same problem before.  Try this:

```
#geog:before
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    content: "";
    background: url("icons/geogebra.ico") no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

I'm sure you'll have to tweak those values, but that worked for me.  Of course, this won't work if you can't set it as a background image for some reason.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows a working example of my solution taken from the code I wrote.  http://jsfiddle.net/CNETx/  I just grabbed an oversized checkmark off a google image search to illustrate the resizing.  I will say I've never tried doing this with an .ico, so I don't know if that format has any strange behavioral issues that might be causing you trouble, but I suspect it should behave the same.  Looking forward to hearing if this works for you!

Comment: Note that this solution uses a _background_ image, rather than a _content_ image; also, the solution uses background-size, which is not supported by, you guessed it, IE8.

Comment: This may be a workaround for many, but I would not consider it a proper solution because as soon as you put it in the background, you can no longer apply foreground effects to it, like shadows etc...  It sure would be nice if width and height applied to the content.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are looking for the `zoom` property. Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70wm1n8u/)

Also you can add spacing with `margin-right` between the icon and the content of the element.

Comment: Thanks; it's definitely the clean and simple solution I was expecting. Interesting that it is considered "Non-standard". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you! This is what i am looking for!

Answer (score -6):

Use PX instead of %

```
#geog:before
{
content: url("icons/geogebra.ico") " ";
height: 5px;
width: 5px;
}
```

Give that a try :-)

Comment: I tried that as well, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if using images as a url content you can't define the size like that, that's why background-size is the best choice