# CSS set content of element to image

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I've got the following class, which works in all the major browsers except Firefox for PC. Specifically the issue is with the `content` being on a regular element—Ffx doesn't seem to like it on anything except a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element. Trouble is, `::after` does not inherit the size of its base element.

html

```html
<span class="col-3 myImg"></span>
```

css

```css
.col-3 {
    width:    25%;
}

.myImg {
  /* content:    url('img.png'); works in everything by Ffx on PC */
  display:    block;
  position:   relative;
}
/* v Needed for Ffx on PC */
.myImg::after {
  background: red;
  content:    url('img.png');
  display:    block;
  max-width:  100%; /* affects only the background colour */
  position:   absolute;
  width:      100%; /* affects only the background colour */
}
```

I don't want to set a height—I want the height to stay proportional to the width (which is determined by `col-#` from bootstrap v3).

I don't want to use a bunch of image tags because that means an update will require a bunch of edits (instead of one central one to the css).

Related SO question: [Can I change the height of an image in CSS :before/:after pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8977957/758177)

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/yuSgN/)

**EDIT** I want the image to be 100% the width of the base element (the span) and the image's height to scale proportionately.

Comment: Why are you putting an image as the background of a pseudo element using CSS? That just sounds like a jarbled mess.

Comment: @CodyGuldner, from my question/post: *I don't want to use a bunch of image tags because that means an update will require a bunch of edits (instead of one central one to the css).*

Comment: so you want the image to have 100% width and stay proportional in height?

Comment: @koala_dev, Yes, I want the image to size to be 100% of the width of the base element and I want its height to scale proportionately.

Comment: I don't think that's possible using the content porperty

Comment: @koala_dev, is there another way to do it without the content property? (proportional height and a width equal to the width of the base element)

Comment: Not that I can think of, you may look into a Javascript solution but of course the easiest thing would be to just use the <img> tag, I know you want a centralized place for future updates, so maybe you can have a constant in PHP where you save the image url?