# How do I resize an image in a pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I'm trying to do some tricks with pseudo-element.

I'm showing a ranking and I want a crown to show on top of the winner, tilted 45 degrees in the corner of the box where the image will be. But the image is too big, is there a way for me to resize an image that is added on a pseudo-element?

I have only this `div`:

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

With this `CSS`:

```css
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

.box::after{
    content: url(URL_OF_IMAGE);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;    
    right: -10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I made an example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GEtds/

I tried altering `height` and `width` but to no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977957/can-i-change-the-height-of-an-image-in-css-before-after-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already using transforms, go a step further. Use them to move and rescale the image:

```
.box::after{
    content: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/5/e/b/12428065451316964828Simple_crown_icon.svg.med.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 0.1em;
    height: 0.1em;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-35px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.2);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-35px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.2);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEtds/5/)

Comment: Nice! Missing a closing parenthesis after the `-moz-transform`.

Comment: @showdev Thanks ! I missed that in the copy-paste .. As you can guess, I am using Chrome.

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer as correct, but could you help me further? In my code it doesn't even show, and I'm not sure why. http://jsfiddle.net/FdT7N/2/

Comment: You can not have pseudo elements on an image. Use the container div instead. http://jsfiddle.net/FdT7N/3/

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by setting the image as `background-image`, in combination with `background-size: cover;` this will let you control the size of the image by setting the `width` and `height` on the pseudo-element. You'll also need to add `content: "";` to ensure the pseudo-element is rendered.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEtds/3/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
.box::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/5/e/b/12428065451316964828Simple_crown_icon.svg.med.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Less reliance on potentially memory-hogging transforms ([which don't seem to play nice with SVG on IE anyway](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)).

Comment: draw-back of this solution is you can't traverse the parent element, or it will appear cut-off.