# CSS - change width of :after elements using content?

Tags: html, css, image

This is my HTML:

```
    <table id='headerBar'>
        <tr>
        <td class='headerBarActualTd'><a href='/' class='headerBarIconLink'></a><a href='/' id='homeIcon'></a></td>
        <td class='headerBarSpacingTd'></td>
        <td class='headerBarActualTd'><a href='/{{ user.username }}/' class='headerBarIconLink'></a><a href='/{{ user.username }}/' id='myProfileIcon'></a></td>
        <td class='headerBarSpacingTd'></td>
        <td class='headerBarActualTd'><a href='/settings/settingsPage/' class='headerBarIconLink'></a><a href='/' id='settingsIcon'></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#settingsIcon::after {
    content:url('soase.png');
    position: relative;
    width: 43px;
}


#homeIcon:after {
    content:url('soase.png');
    position: relative;
     width: 43px;
}

#myProfileIcon:after {
    content:url('soase.png');
    position: relative;
    width: 43px;
}
```

In the CSS I set width of the images to 43px but it does not work. The images just appear their regular image size. I even tried using

```
background-size: 43px;
```

and that didn't work either. I found this:
[Can I change the height of an image in CSS :before/:after pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977957/can-i-change-the-height-of-an-image-in-css-before-after-pseudo-elements)

but it requires me to change

```
content
```

to

```
background-image
```

but I don't want to do that because background-image was giving my cross browser issues (if I remember correctly, it wasn't showing up correctly on IE.

How do I change the width of the :after element which links to an image using 'content'?

Comment: Background-image property http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size  I think this is quite enough ie 8+

Comment: @CroaToa hm what do you mean by "I think this is wuite enough ie 8+"?

Comment: I meant that background-image do not support browsers which have very few users

Comment: @CroaToa thing is, the app I am creating is for a few workplaces and the workplaces still use IE8

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overflow: hidden;` to ::after and write width and height.

See [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7T8Jc/1/)

Comment: hm that ends up cropping the large image rather than actually changing the images width.