# CSS - The ::after Pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to put the image before span element. But image is so big. Can I change the size of image with using  the ::after pseudo-element?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your working code! Now, after reading your question, everything here is imaginative ! And different people can have different imaginations ! :)

Comment: section span::before {
  content: url("images/user.png");
 }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the height of an image in CSS :before/:after pseudo-elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977957/can-i-change-the-height-of-an-image-in-css-before-after-pseudo-elements)

Comment: everything is ok but I want to change the size of image.

Comment: Hey, add that code in your question itself - like go for Edit option and add there. 
But, now you have shared this little snippet  - use `span: before {content:'';background-image: url("images/user.png") no-repeat cover;Width: something;height: something;display:block; }`

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot ! I look at it now, it's new for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can add image before `<span>`.

```css
span{
  margin-left:100px;
}
span:before{
  content:'';
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  left:5px;
  position:absolute;
  background-image : url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
}
```

```html
<span> hi </span>
```

Comment: Thanks. ) it's new way for me.

Comment: Welcome @ChristinaShahoyan hope it worked for you, if so accept the answer :-)

Comment: Accepted. I am new here and I saw it just now ;)