# How do I change size of content url picture using ::after / ::before Pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

First is the code that I want to change.

```
<style>
  h1::after {
    content: url(sig01.png);
  }
</style>
```

Second is what I tried, but not working.

```
<style>
    h1::after {
        content: url(sig01.png);
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You won't be able to do it by using image directly inside content. You can set the image as background and then manipulate the background size instead. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8978010/3345535 for an example.

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. Its very difficult to understand what is exact problem? what you tried? what error you got? what are the data samples if any etc etc.. things missing in the post. also along with this things elaborate the problem more.

Comment: Code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You can't resize a content-image, but you can work around by using `background-image` instead of `content`.

```
<style>
h1::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(sig01.png);
  background-size: 200px;
}
</style>
```